# How to Plot Candlestick chart and indicators Using quantmod?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, quantmod

A few days back, accidentally, I  was able to plot technical indicators using these codes

> ch.add_BBANDS()
>
> ch.add_RSI(14)

But now I am not able to do so as I am having a problem installing quantmod.

I know we can plot candlestick chart by using plotly but with quantmod there seems to be a single line code which would be easier.

I realized that the problem is in Installing and importing [quantmod](https://github.com/jackluo/py-quantmod) as it says:

*ImportError:
The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead.*

I also tried to degrade my plotly version as mentioned [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1660) but nothing worked. I want to know if someone has been able to install and import quantmod in jupyter notebook and plot some of the  charts as indicated by following codes. I would appreciate if you show me the correct way to get quantmod working in my jupyter notebook.

> ch = qm.Chart(df)
>
> ch.to_figure(type='ohlc', dimensions=(2560,1440))
>
> ch = qm.Chart(df)
>
> ch.add_BBANDS()
>
> ch.add_RSI(14)
>
> ch.to_figure(type='candlestick', title='EQUITY')

Answer (score 0):

Try using QuantFig to get what you are trying to get. Chart studio now requires a sign in. QuantFig uses the index of the pandas dataframe as the x axis for the chart. So take care to format it. the columns shall be named 'open', 'high', 'low', close' as it is expected by QuantFig. you can use the following snippet for inspiration.

```
    import chart_studio.plotly as py
    import cufflinks as cf
    import python as pd

    py.sign_in('Python-Demo-Account', 'gwt101uhh0')

    def plotData(df=None):
        if df == None:
            df=cf.datagen.ohlc()
        qf=cf.QuantFig(df,title='First Quant Figure',legend='top',name='GS')
        qf.add_bollinger_bands()
        qf.add_rsi()
        fig = qf.iplot(asFigure=True)
        fig.show()

    plotData()
```